# Telling faces apart from photos of faces with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm building an AR toy, and following this tutorial over here https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html I've already managed to match different testers' faces to the Local Binary Patterns Histograms.

My problem is, I'm also matching photos of this people as if they were them. Can anyone please point me to papers on how to differentiate this two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To detect that a "face" is just a still image I can come up with a simple algorithm which can be implemented using OpenCV's functionality.

Once a *new* face appears in the frame (that is a solved problem, I suppose), calculate a rough bounding box of the face and store an image of the face to some buffer. Let's call this fragment containing face the "Face1" image.

For each new frame (if *the same* face is detected there) try to extract face's image (we'll call that fragment "FaceN") and then calculate a homography to the first frame ("Face1" image). Then warp the "FaceN" image to align it with "Face1" and try running some comparison between pixels. If the "FaceN" image is "too static" (some heuristics needed here), then it probably is a photo.

I understand this is

1. not really fast
2. not really robust

but I'm pretty sure it might be a starting point with some optimizations later.

The whole approach can be tested on just two still frames of you holding a face's photo in front of the camera (this would be "Face1" and "FaceN" images).